# Convert Drawable/Bitmap to ResourceID (android)

Tags: android, resources, bitmap, drawable

So I need to have an icon based in an Image I have on my SDCARD, but I can only get the Drawable/Bitmap, how can I get the int resource based on that?

```
public static String SDCARD_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/folder/";

public static Drawable getDrawableFromChannelID(int id) {
    return Drawable.createFromPath(Utils.SDCARD_PATH + id + ".png");
}

public static Bitmap getBitmapFromChannelID(int id) {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Utils.SDCARD_PATH + id + ".png");
}
```

Comment: what did you end up doing?

Comment: Hey, it looks like it's impossible :/ look at @shesmile answer, best of luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yah, I believe you can't do that. You have to manually add the image in the resource to get the id or you can add add it as ImageView in your contentview and add an Id on it, just set its visibility to Gone, so that, it will not affect your other layout, like this

```
   ImageView icon=new ImageView(this);
   img.setBackground(<urDrawableIcon>);
   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams iconlayout=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   icon.setId(11111);//set your own id;
   icon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   addContentView(icon,iconlayout);

   //so your id is 11111; NotificationBuilder.setIcon(11111);
```

Comment: I need it for the NotificationBuilder.setIcon(res), and the icons are only downloaded after the first run, I like your approach thou

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't. All the R.id.. etc are the resources [included in your apk](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html). Why do you need a resource id anyway?

Comment: I need it for the NotificationBuilder.setIcon(res), and the icons are only downloaded after the first run